# How to add hyperlink to a word which is a part of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, hyperlink, anchor, string-concatenation

I've one string and a link, as follows :

```
$link = 'https://www.google.co.in';
$str = 'Hi all welcome to the google page Google Page';
```

Now I want to make the word **'Google Page'** a hyper link. When the whole string($str) will appear on a web page the string **'Google Page'** should appear as a hyperlink and upon click on it the link `'https://www.google.co.in'` should get open.

For achieving this I tried following code but no success.

```
Phpfox::getUserBy('full_name').' accepted your request to join'.<a href=$sLink>Google Page</a>Group Name
echo 'Hi all welcome to the google page <a href=$link> '.Google Page'.'</a>'';
```

Can someone please help me and correct the mistake I'm  making in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your string in single quotes. When you single quote your string, you are telling PHP to display the string *as-is*. Thus, the `$link` variable will not be interpreted.

An alternative to [MuthaFury's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33294533/4833127) is to change your single quotes to double quotes to tell php that you do want the `$link` variable interpreted.

```
echo "Hi all welcome to the google page <a href=\"$link\">Google Page</a>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
echo 'Hi all welcome to the google page <a href="'.$link.'">Google Page</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = 'https://www.google.co.in';
$str = 'Hi all welcome to the google page Google Page and another Google Page just for test';
$word = 'Google Page';
echo str_replace($word, "<a href=\"{$link}\">{$word}</a>", $str);
```

Comment: Nice idea, although might not work so good if there's also `Google Pages`, `Google Pagerank`, etc. within the text.